# C# auto-property snippet puts get and set on new line

Tags: c#, code-snippets

In Visual Studio 2015 when I type `prop` and then hit tab I invoke the auto-property snippet and get this:

```
public property int MyProperty
{ get; set; }
```

But what I want is this:

```
public property MyProperty { get; set; }
```

**How can I make the snippet place the code on 1 line?**

I've checked the XML file at:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC#\Snippets\1033\Visual C#\prop.snippet

But it looks okay to me:

```
<Declarations>
    <Literal>
        <ID>type</ID>
        <ToolTip>Property type</ToolTip>
        <Default>int</Default>
    </Literal>
    <Literal>
        <ID>property</ID>
        <ToolTip>Property name</ToolTip>
        <Default>MyProperty</Default>
    </Literal>
</Declarations>
<Code Language="csharp"><![CDATA[public $type$ $property$ { get; set; }$end$]]>
</Code>
```

I have not got ReSharper installed.

Comment: Odd. I cannot reproduce on my machine (VS2015 Enterprise). Is it possible that some other extension is messing with the code? Have you tried disabling all extensions?

Comment: My guess is it's another extension, something that always puts the `{` on a new line.

Answer (score 5):

In `Options > Text Editor > C# > Formatting > Wrapping` I have it set to:

[image]

By checking both of these I get the results I want.  It's a little unintuitive as both options affect both results (as opposed to the top option affecting the top result and the bottom option affecting the bottom result), and as such, I have to now allow this when I don't want to:

```
int i = 0; string name = "John";
```

Ah well, problem (kinda) solved.

Comment: My advice would be to reset to default formatting and never deviate. It's good enough, actually quite good.